# PHP Class COM for Outlook not open outlook

Tags: php, com

I have used below code for open outlook by PHP COM method. But outlook not open and it is loading & loading. no response, not open outlook, only loading & loading. Please give solution how to open outlook by PHP COM method. I have installed Office Outlook & also have MAPI.Session & also have Outlook.Application.

```
if (! defined ( "olMailItem" ))
{
define ("olMailItem", 0 );
}
try {
$objApp = new COM ( "Outlook.Application" ) or die ( "Cannot Load Outlook.Application" );
$namespace = $objApp->GetNamespace("MAPI"); 
$namespace->Logon();
$myItem = $objApp->CreateItem ( olMailItem );
$myItem->To = "yusuf.khalil88@gmail.com";
$myItem->SentOnBehalfOfName = "yusuf_khalil88@yahoo.com";
$myItem->Subject = "Hi Response me";
$myItem->Body = "I want to find out";
$myItem->Send ();
}catch ( Exception $e ) {
var_dump ( $e->getMessage () );
debug_print_backtrace ();
}
```

Comment: Please give a solution. How to open outlook by PHP. Please Give

Comment: Chances are that the process hosting PHP (IIS, Apache, whatever) doesn't actually have permission to invoke Outlook.  Does this script work for you at the command line?  If so, then good, it's just a permissions issue.  And no, I don't know what would need to change... something about service accounts interacting with desktop applications.

Comment: How set permission to invoke Outlook? (Apache)

Answer (score 0):

I just found another solution from this page: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/php-com-automating-outlook-46167.html

Basically PHP doesn't have the constants like olMailList, so you have to refer to it by values. So to make your current script work change this line:

```
$myItem = $objApp->CreateItem(olMailItem);
```

to:

```
$myItem = $objApp->CreateItem(0);
```

That worked just fine for my situation.